# How to deal with "this is fixed in X" and "This is a bug" answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

How should we handle answers like https://stackoverflow.com/a/23229273/1149495 ("*I fixed it in version 2.05.*") or https://stackoverflow.com/a/1825023/1149495 ("*This is a bug*")?

They don't provide any context on the answer and are usually link only answers, so that'll make me click on the "flag" button quite fast. On the other hand, most of the time it is the only valid answer to a question (except from "work-around" solutions).

If a bug is fixed, the question itself also comes in the range of the "a problem that can no longer be reproduced" close reason.

Should the question be closed and the post be flagged? Or maybe do nothing with the flag and only close the question? Or should the post remain open (since the asker didn't do anything wrong) and the answer be flagged? Or do we call this a valid answer for SO?

Comment: Think about this in a "we are a DB for people searching for stuff" way: someone has the same problem, comes to SO, reads the answer and is happy to find the cause for his problem (or not).

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132701/

Comment: "If a bug is fixed, the question itself also comes in the range of the 'a problem that can no longer be reproduced' close reason.", not exactly true. If people still use older versions that contain the bug, the problem will eventually be reproduced.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Saying that a given behavior is a bug in the language is an acceptable answer, including a reference to a reputable source supporting that assertion is a nice addition.  Ideally a suitable workaround would be included, if relevant to the question.

An answer indicating that a given behavior was changed in a given version of the product is also fine, and including a reference to corresponding patch notes is, again, a nice addition.  This is not "unable to be reproduced" as there are still undoubtedly plenty of people still using the previous version of that product; they can search for solutions to this problem, and see that they need to upgrade.  Again, including suitable workaround for the problem (besides upgrading) if relevant to the question is a good improvement to the answer.

In both cases the question is answered without the link.  The link helps the answer, but the question is still answered even if the link goes nowhere.  There is no reason to flag such an answer as "Not an Answer".

At worst such an answer could be of low quality if you feel that it fails to go into sufficient depth, but I wouldn't even see it as Very Low Quality (i.e. meriting deletion) rather only a downvote at best for failing to elaborate on what the bug is, how it can be worked around, etc.  And of course even that is a matter of judgement; not all such answers of this from are of low quality.

Comment: And: if a question has a short answer, then so be it.

Answer (score 11):

Is it the correct answer?

- If yes, upvote
- If no, downvote and comment.

Really, I don't see the problem. If the user is having a problem with a particular version of some software due to a bug, and a legitimate solution is to patch the software, then that seems to me like the correct answer!

If the answer seems too short, or is just a link, maybe leave a comment asking the poster to expand on it *a little bit*.

Comment: should say "If no, comment and downvote."   Never. Ever. downvote without commenting. If the answer is so absurd it doesn't even merit a comment, flag it.

Comment: @Okuma.Tony: If an answer should be downvoted, please downvote it. Period. Commenting is also an excellent way to help out, but it should *not* be seen as some sort of prerequisite to downvoting.

Comment: @ruakh Can you think of an example where down-voting without a reason is preferable to down+comment or simply flagging? Answer is wrong: downvote and say why so no-one is lead astray. If it's "Very Low Quality" or "Not an Answer" etc, Flag it as such.

Comment: @Okuma.Tony: I *can* think of such cases, but I'm not even talking about those. My point is that even if downvote+comment is better than just_downvote in a given case, just_downvote will still be better than don't_even_downvote. There's a reason that the software doesn't require you to comment when you downvote, and the reason is that we *want* people to downvote when appropriate, even if they lack the time, inclination, or ability to post a productive comment.

Comment: @Still.Tony I'd say that comment didn't age well, but I don't think it was born well either.

Answer (score 5):

As far as closing the question itself, I would personally think that historical information like this is useful for developers to have - sometimes older versions of software are used and having the workaround solutions are helpful.

Regarding the 'quick fix' answers, they aren't high-quality answers by SO standards. If the answer explained the fix and then linked, they would both provide information about the problem AND the solution, which in my experience is the most valuable.

I don't believe flagging would be the best way to get the answering user to update their answer - though I have no evidence on this (perhaps it -is- the best way). If not, then it's potentially harmful, for the link itself is better than no information.

Ideally, they would be told (via comment and/or downvotes) to update their answer, and would then proceed to update it.

edit:
An additional thought I had: Without explanation, there is no guarantee that the link posted -actually- fixed the problem the OP was having. It may have been a misunderstanding. People visiting the question and reading the answer may be mislead, however with corresponding details on the answer itself, it could be identified as valid/invalid easily (which is the biggest advantage of Q/A sites like SO)