# Use of "bug" tag for Google products

Tags: discussion, tags, outsourcing, product-support

Google have stated to its developers that all developer support will be done on Stack Overflow. For help-and-advice type support, that is fine and is working well.

However, "support" covers a myriad of scenarios and situations. For example, reporting, sharing and monitoring open bugs is part of support.

So I'm requesting approval to add a 'bug' tag to those Stack Overflow questions where either the question is of the form of "I've found a bug with xxxxx", or where the answer is "I know your problem, it's a Google bug". Currently developers are wasting man years of time on problems that are turning out to be bugs which are outside of their control.

For the avoidance of any doubt, I am **not** suggesting that Stack Overflow be used a bug tracking system. Simply for the sanction to mark questions as bugs when that is in fact what they are.

See also [How to deal with "this is fixed in X" and "This is a bug" answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251718/how-to-deal-with-this-is-fixed-in-x-and-this-is-a-bug-answers/251720#251720)

**Conclusion:**
There is a clear dissonance between the Stack Overflow community's view as expressed in responses to this thread, and Google's view as expressed in a variety of Google pages and previous answers. This dissonance is leaving Google developers between a rock and a hard place. If they play by Google's rules, they get flamed on Stack Overflow. If they don't, there is no alternative support process.

Comment: The fact that Google says that they want questions of a certain form to be posted here doesn't make them on topic here.

Comment: They can dream about SO being their free-of-charge support helpdesk as long as they rake in the cash.

Comment: SO is not a site for bug-reports. It is entirely up to Google to provide the adequate means for bug reporting and tracking. So no, a bug tag should most definitely not be added. P.s. if they explicitly state to take your bug reports here, please share that link with us. It will need to be changed.

Comment: google have plenty of money, it's very cheeky of them to say that support is going to be handled by a third party. What if Apple and Microsoft announced that support was going to be handled by SO in the future?

Comment: @Bart https://developers.google.com/drive/ scroll to the bottom and click support

Comment: I think what Google meant by that link is to ask development/programming issue, since it's related to Drive API (just like what they have done with Android). But it doesn't mean to post bug report (more assumed to Drive, not the API itself) since I believe Google just use their forums/Google Code for bug tracking.

Comment: @AndrewT. sorry, but you're wrong. The question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23233782/google-drive-not-persisting-put-changes asks "This should probably be a bug report, but I am unable to find where to submit this to Google as Drive SDK support page says to come to StackOverflow.", and Google's answer says " For bug reports, here [ SO ] or the G+ page are both good places to report issues".

Comment: Thanks for the question as confirmation. Though, I'm confused for Google's decision about this... really, if it's a bug, why don't they use Google Code with its already integrated bug tracker? (Edit: the rest of the comment was regarding to what will Google do after it's been fixed, which was already mentioned in Servy's answer.)

Comment: Google closed the support forum and provided no bug tracker for most of their products. See this discussion https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/EgCgsuQbfvA post from "TreKing" "Google dropped official support for this forum quite some time ago, in favor of StackOverflow. There was a post, either in this group or the dev blog, or somewhere (can't find it now) announcing such. After that, Googlers (D. Hackborn et al) and more prominent members like Mark Murphy slowly stopped posting, and the traffic has been in perpetual decline."

Comment: since reporting bug on StackOverflow is not correct I asked where to report them, it was closed as off-topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33342680/where-do-you-file-bugs-for-android-ios-google-products-or-services-appinvites

Answer (score 29):

If the answer to a question is, "It's a bug with the framework" then that's fine, but there's no need to tag the question with [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug).  It is a meta-tag, which is not what the tagging system is designed for.  It is a property about the answer (not even the question, really) and isn't a means of categorizing it.

As for a post saying, "I've found a bug with xxxxx"  That's not a question.  SO is not a bug tracking/reporting tool; such a post is not appropriate here, and so obviously there need be no tag for such questions.

Comment: so that seems pretty unanimous. Who's gonna tell Google?

Comment: @pinoyyid As is described in [this comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251838/use-of-bug-tag-for-google-products/251846?noredirect=1#comment5005_251838) you appear to be mis-interpreting Google's instructions, rather than that they're actually telling people to report bugs though SO rather than their bug tracking mechanisms.

Comment: @Servy: considering their Support link goes to a box to ask a question on SO without any intervening explanation of when you should and shouldn't do that, I don't think it's too misintepreted. Someone at Google screwed up, IMO.

Comment: @Servy I haven't misinterpreted anything. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23233782/google-drive-not-persisting-put-changes

Comment: I just hope that question will be answered according to what guideline is correct, otherwise SO will have many unanswered bug reports here...

Comment: @pinoyyid The comment, (while, granted, still not as clear as it should be) indicates that SO should be the place to go if you need help solving a problem that may or may not be a bug.  G+ is where you go to report what you believe is a bug.  That analysis is of course correct, despite being, again, misleading/confusing.

Comment: It's really their intention to have bugs reported in SO. Before, they have a Google Group for that but decided to transition to SO: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-documents-list-api/8R_q70c5WPk . -- another Google Drive developer