# Are questions like "Where do I report bug for product/platform/sdk X?" on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, site-recommendation

NOTE: this question was briefly, wrongly, closed as duplicate of another. This question is about whether asking where to report a bug for a platform is on-topic. The duplicate was about whether a question that is asking whether some behaviour is a bug is on-topic.

A while ago I asked [Where do you file bugs for Android/iOS Google Products or Services (AppInvites, Maps, etc…)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33342680/where-do-you-file-bugs-for-android-ios-google-products-or-services-appinvites)  on Stack Overflow, and it was closed as *off-topic: not about programming*.  I've read [the help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and I think my question is on topic.

Specifically, my question is about Google Play Services, which falls into the "software tools commonly used by programmers" definition, and it was asking how to report a bug found in that library, which I think matches "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development".

I personally consider bug reporting part of programming. It's not only a good practice, it's often necessary. Specially when the bug is causing you some big issue and you can't do much about it other then ask the library owner to fix it.

I can see this is borderline case. I would like to know what the community thinks about it.

Finally, if it is off-topic on Stack Overflow is there another Stack Exchange community where it would be on-topic? If so, is there a way to migrate my question there?

EDIT: Asking for a link is off topic in Stack Overflow. But is this the right way to judge it?

I mean, the link changed, project forked, weird stuff making it hard to track the "right" URL. Isn't that something more then just asking to act as a proxy for a google search?

I spent hours trying to figure out what's was going on before resulting to write on SO, finding out from other users that's wasn't actually an easy task nor someone had a solution.

It require that same thing you need when you have a problem with programming: someone with experience that followed the project closely. My point here is that probably we are using the wrong method to define what's off topic and what's not.

I think the way we should decide if something is in-topic or off-topic is "is it a straight forward reply? Only a google search away or does it require someone with experience to reply this question?".

Comment: @halfer first link in your comment is broken. The second post suggest that I should ask "how" to fix something I already know its a bug in the hope that someone will tell me where to report it. It's fine when you do not know its a bug, but when you know it's just a waste of everyone resource.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company

Comment: Apologies, new link here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251838/use-of-bug-tag-for-google-products and also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284708/what-can-we-do-with-questions-where-the-only-response-is-contact-the-vendor/284722 (deleted other comment).

Comment: thanks @Mat contacting stack overflow to say the company (Google) didn't left clear indication on how to report bugs on their products is actually a great idea.

Comment: @halfer first like very interesting too, it's exactly the same situation i'm talking about with the difference that I didn't reported the bug on stack overflow, I asked where to report it :)

Comment: That's only a good idea _if_ google's support pages redirect to SO for support. If they don't, SO has nothing to do with it.

Comment: It's a resource request - those are unanimously off topic even when it's about programming. Not that being able to ask such things wouldn't be nice - but there are too many problems associated with them

Comment: @Pekka웃 I would probably agree with you if it wasn't for the fact that Google a while ago closed their products forums, where people reported bugs, saying to use StackOverflow. Bug reporting on stack overflow is off-topic, I know that. But they said it anyway and we, developers, now have NO place to report bugs on Google products. Isn't this situation in itself enough to make of this an exception?

Comment: @DanieleSegato ...no? Why should SO let Google off the hook?

Comment: @jonrsharpe it's not about Google, it's about the situation

Comment: I sympathize, but.... `Isn't this situation in itself enough to make of this an exception?` - not really, IMO. It's Google's problem to fix, not ours.

Comment: @gnat what? No! This question is about whether *asking where to report a bug for a platform* is on-topic. The question you've linked is about whether a question that is *asking whether some behaviour is a bug* is on-topic. There is literally zero overlap whatsoever between the two questions.

Comment: @gnat uh, that's pretty contestable too; given that for most projects there is (at least at any given moment in time) *exactly one* objectively correct place to report bugs, there's at least a case to be made that asking where to report bugs is different to other off-site resource questions. I'd let this question stand and allow the discussion to run its course.

Comment: I don't have much to provide, but I think this is a much bigger [problem](https://developers.google.com/app-invites/) and I'm curious what you guys think. Check the help.. and then see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-app-invites)...

Comment: @CayceK yep, that's the problem. lot of bug reports on SO because Google redirect to it for "Help" and provide no other means of reporting bugs. That's surely Google fault, we all agree on that. But there's a lot of wasted effort and frustration coming from the fact we, developers, have no way of reporting bugs. Wouldn't help to have a question like mine standing in place with lot of upvotes and link to it on every bug report? Wouldn't it raise attention on Google? And aside from that, isn't it legit to ask where to report bugs? I honestly think it's not different then asking how to use api.

Comment: @DanieleSegato ... I don't know if the dupe setting is right. This solution sure won't help what's happening in any way... It also seems that Google doesn't believe they have bugs to worry about. And if they do their users will find a way around them..

Comment: *exactly one objectively correct place to report bugs* @MarkAmery - That doesn't change that it's still a find request. That they tend to attract spam and opinionated answers may be why they're off topic, but the rule still applies to all find/rec requests.

Comment: why marking this as duplicate? As Mark pointed out this question has nothing to do with a bug report, it's about bug reporting. Please reopen it

Comment: Potential compromise: Put the link for reporting bugs, if there is one, in the tag wiki. Most good tag wikis have links to resources for their topic. I don't see a reason why the bug report page shouldn't be one of them. If there isn't a place to report bugs, there can be a note about that.

Comment: *is there another Stack Exchange community where it would be on-topic* - This also might be something Documentation can take care of but someone in the beta would need to speak to that.

Comment: @DanieleSegato: I think ultimately you may have to concede defeat on this one. Google has made it harder for Google developers to report bugs, and would like volunteers here to pick up the slack. Stack Overflow's community has replied by saying that it is not impressed. The ball is in Google's court, I think, and we'd be unfairly letting them off the hook if we felt that they warranted an exception.

Comment: @halfer I don't see the relevance of your last comment; Daniele hasn't tried to report bugs on Stack Overflow, isn't asking about whether it's okay to report bugs on Stack Overflow, and isn't advocating allowing bugs to be reported on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks @Mark. I must have missed something, in that case - would you explain what Daniele has tried to do, so I can respond to the thrust of your remark? It seems to me that if Google have closed an avenue for reporting bugs on their own sites, and are pointing devs to SO, then questions that either file bugs here or ask where to file them are inevitable, and they should be pushed back to Google. Do you feel the question on the main site should be re-opened?

Comment: @halfer he's tried to [ask on Stack Overflow where to report bugs for a given platform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33342680/where-do-you-file-bugs-for-android-ios-google-products-or-services-appinvites). That may still be something we don't wish to allow (although personally I'm more permissive on this kind of stuff than most voices on Meta and would happily allow this question, or indeed pretty much any programming-related question that will have value to future readers). But it's definitely not the same as reporting a bug on Stack Overflow itself, and the dupe closure here is wrong.

Comment: Ah, see what you mean @Mark. Agree with the close vote here certainly, voted to reopen.

Comment: I want to edit the question using Mark words to explain why this is different then "is off-topic to bug report". Will I lose the reopen votes if I edit the question now? I only need 1 more vote to reopen the question.

Comment: I feel that we need a meta-meta-stackoverflow for such questions :p

Comment: @MrTJ [hey there] actually meta is for this kind of questions :)

Comment: @Daniele: no, if you edit a post that has reopen votes, you do not lost them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> it was closed as off-topic: not about programming.

No, it was closed because:

> This question does not appear to be about programming **within the scope defined in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**:
>
> - a specific programming problem, or (no)
> - a software algorithm, or (no)
> - software tools commonly used by programmers (no<sup>1</sup>); **and** is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development (so, no)

You're asking:

> where do I file a bug

Which is a request for an off-site resource, namely "please link me to Google's bug reporting page".

<sup>1</sup>: you can say "bug reporting software is a tool commonly used by developers", but this is not a question *about* a particular piece of bug reporting software, it's a resource request, which are off-topic:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial **or other off-site resource** are off-topic

So while I think this particular question might be interesting and helpful for others, it simply is not within the scope of this site.

Comment: Isn't it different when there is no clear link? I mean, the link changed, project forked, weird stuff making it hard to track the "right" URL. Isn't that something more then just asking to act as a proxy for a google search? It require that same thing you need when you have a problem with programming: someone with experience that followed the project closely. My point here is that probably we are using the wrong method to define what's off topic and what's not.

Comment: @DanieleSegato Sure, it's different, but only in that instead of just asking for a link, you're asking SO users to do the full, time-consuming search for the link _for you._ You're _still asking for a link._ You still want an off-site resource. And someone will be expected to keep that answer up-to-date! So if Google changes the location 50 times in the next year, some poor soul, probably the answer author, will be stuck keeping up with it, deleting their answer, or dealing with frequent "but this doesn't work!" comments when the link changes again.

Comment: @Kendra I expect someone who already know to tell me, not asking anyone to do the hard work. I'm even usually willing to keep answer up to date if i can. when i post a question like that it's because i already tried hard to find it myself and failed. the amount of upvotes and comments I've received prove it was an actually meaningful question for which the answer is valuable to many. I get it why you usually file does kind of questions as off topic. But what about exceptions like this one? are you all so sure it makes sense to mark them as off topic regardless of how the community react to it?

Comment: I'll leave this answer stand for a week to see if someone else have different opinion. If none well.. means I'm the only one seeing it differently, which probably means I'm wrong :) so I'll mark this as accepted answer

Comment: marked as accepted answer. Still think stackoverflow should do something about companies saying to use it for bug reporting, but this is probably another topic on its own

Comment: @Daniele: What would you propose SO do? They have no control over what an outside source says on their site. We do what we can here by making sure that questions remain on topic no matter what the companies might say. If you have issues with a company misdirecting questions here, address it with the company and link to questions you've asked here that were closed as off-topic; maybe they'll learn.