# What is the problem with this question? Extremely similar questions have been well received

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed, quality-improvement

I have recently asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74539337/12287457) on Stack Overflow regarding a compiler bug in [VBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications). The exact bug I described has never been described online before, at least to my knowledge. It is a variation of a bug that has been known, but it was assumed to be fixed by the community.

When I posted my question, my style was a little sarcastic, which led to the question being closed. I thereafter edited it to be completely neutral and it now makes the following key points:

1. There is a bug. Are there other variations of the bug I have overlooked?
2. There seems to be no way to report such bugs to the developers of the language, have I overlooked such a way?

Both of these points have been made in exactly this fashion in previous questions:

1. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65041832/12287457) is one of my own questions.
2. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68034271/12287457) is a question about the same thing half a year later making point 2 instead of 1.

Both of these questions were very well received.

What is the problem with my new question in comparison to these old questions?

I would like to improve my current question, but I'm not getting any feedback.

I do not understand at all in what way it is currently "opinion based"?

I think that my questions are on-topic for Stack Overflow. According to [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), questions about

1. a specific programming problem, or
2. a software algorithm, or
3. software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
4. a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

are on-topic.

I would argue that "Are there other ways in which this bug can manifest?", after providing an exhaustive list of the ways known to me, constitutes a question of categories 1), 3) and 4).

While "Is there a way of filing a bug report that has been demonstrated to be effective apart from media coverage?" is a question of type 3), about the "software tool" VBA compiler.

In fact, I'm quite baffled at this comment as a quick Google search revealed countless questions along the lines of "How do I file a bug report?", most of them, contrary to mine, were very low-effort questions, and only the lowest effort ones are closed, and even those not for being off-topic.

Here is a small selection of the ones I instantly found:

- [How to report Zenity bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36783171/how-to-report-zenity-bugs)
- [How do I report a bug in Kentico 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38646775/how-do-i-report-a-bug-in-kentico-9?rq=1)
- [Report a bug or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69999717/report-a-bug-or-not)
- [How and where can I report a bug in a RADStudio GetIt package, specifically for the googletest package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73887005/how-and-where-can-i-report-a-bug-in-a-radstudio-getit-package-specifically-for)
- [Where to report bugs for Vagrant boxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62762012/where-to-report-bugs-for-vagrant-boxes)
- [Understanding Bug Report in Android Development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71614200/understanding-bug-report-in-android-development)
- [How to report a bug to Mulesoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67448594/how-to-report-a-bug-to-mulesoft)
- [Where to report PyQT5 bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44830032/where-to-report-pyqt5-bug)
- [Where do I report bugs in the code examples of the sklearn documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57113509/where-do-i-report-bugs-in-the-code-examples-of-the-sklearn-documentation)
- [How to file a bug for the AOSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74479773/how-to-file-a-bug-for-the-aosp)
- [Got an error with class composition, where can I report the bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72935177/got-an-error-with-class-composition-where-can-i-report-the-bug)
- [How do I report a bug in Roblox Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52044196/how-do-i-report-a-bug-in-roblox-studio)

Also, I have to add that my question isn't even closed for being off-topic, but for being "opinion-based".

Comment: Can you please clarify in what way "Are there other variations of this bug I am currently not aware of?" or "Is there a way of filing a bug report that has been demonstrated to be effective apart from media coverage?" are on-topic for SO? ("similar questions were not closed before" is not a way to justify)

Comment: According to [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) both of these questions are about a software tool commonly used by programmers (the VBA compiler) and some problems I'm having with it. The first of these can also be considered a specific programming problem. I think finding ways to make a bug manifest when I have provided all the ways I could come up with is exactly that. Additionally, look at the comment by @Jeremy Caney to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65259128/12287457) please. Also, can you please explain how these questions are opinion based?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, please have a look at my updated question.

Comment: Oh! and since you seem to be working at Microsoft according to your profile, can you please forward the questions to your colleagues? If they manage to implement a fix I don't mind keeping it closed, that would be the ideal outcome!

Comment: "There seems to be no way to report such bugs to the language developers" - I hope you realize that reporting the bug to us, the Stack Overflow community, isn't what you should be doing unless you are looking for a way to work around the bug. I see a pattern in your question history, you are reporting VBA bugs, to us a community of random developers.

Comment: @SecurityHound I strongly disagree for multiple reasons. First, it is very valuable to know about such bugs as a developer (especially in VBA, as bugs almost never get fixed). Second, reporting a bug here on SO has actually resulted in the only successful bug report I have ever witnessed on this language. I have only ever reported two of these bugs and I am desperately looking for a better way to report these bugs, that is what my question is about!!!

Comment: @GWD - Stack Overflow isn't a bug reporting service, we don't track issues for programming languages, we answer questions about code.  As for your most recent question, I would argue, "Does anyone know of a way to report such bugs that will actually get them fixed?" isn't within the defined scope of Stack Overflow. You are asking our opinion on the reason your last question was closed, I provided my opinion, as a user who has been around more than a decade

Comment: @SecurityHound regarding "Stack Overflow isn't a bug reporting service": I agree with this, which is why I'm asking where to find the bug reporting service. Regarding your second point: I have expressed my surprise at this being off-topic in multiple places now, and the double standard comparing it to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68034271/12287457) seems extreme to me.

Comment: @GWD - Just because what you want to report has to do with programming does not mean, Stack Overflow, is the correct Stack Exchange community for asking WHERE to report the bug. Your linked question in your comment is focus and asks a within scope question, your last question which is closed, does not ask a within scope question.

Comment: @SecurityHound, I have now rephrased that question to "Is there a way of filing a report about this bug that will actually reach the developers of VBA?". Is this now closed scope enough?

Comment: Way too much meta commentary in that question, it reads more like a blog post than a question.

Comment: @user438383, can you tell me what exactly you consider irrelevant?

Comment: @GWD the history and background section is IMO - how has references to media attention got anything to do with a practical programming issue? and any references to actually filing a bug report is also probably off-topic.

Comment: @user438383 I'm still not convinced that this is off topic because in my opinion it falls under software tools used for programming. And the only other questions asking this question I have ever seen getting closed were extremely low quality. Please look at the questions I linked in my meta post... I think the history and background section is indeed interesting for anyone who is genuinely interested in the question, and those who just want to quickly see the code do not do not have to read it, as it is a clearly marked section.

Comment: @GWD just because something is interesting doesn’t mean it’s on topic.

Comment: Related: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: You know it's a rant. You just want to rant. This is not the place.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are questions like "Where do I report bug for product/platform/sdk X?" on-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317061/are-questions-like-where-do-i-report-bug-for-product-platform-sdk-x-on-topic) and also [Are bug report-ish questions in the scope of SO?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308010/are-bug-report-ish-questions-in-the-scope-of-so) these 2 questions should answer your question along with a few others that would be related.

Comment: No, I can't help you with reporting the issue as I don't know anyone who may help. If I found such issue myself I likely would not even bother reporting - if after 10+ years issue with legacy tech was not really found chances that it is going to be fixed are low... Creating Q&A on SO to show workaround would be my choice. Indeed your route is also valid, but SO is not the place to rant - you already identified a news outlet that may be interested with such story, also news don't really like re-running essentially the same stories so may need another place. Maybe Twitter 2.0?

Comment: Thank you for your reply @AlexeiLevenkov. Unfortunately, I do not see myself going to these lengths. The reason I posted the question was that I wanted to help people. I don't really care too much about the bug myself, I know about it and I know how to work around it. I have spent a significant amount of time in recent months writing up posts like this in order to help. I want to thank all of you for showing me that I am wasting my time.

Comment: Please don't rage quit. I don't think you are far off. If you want to document a compiler bug (that future readers would be helped by finding through search engines), then it just needs to be done in the right way. From the help center: *"Stack Exchange has always explicitly encouraged users to answer their own questions. If you have a question that you already know the answer to, and you would like to document that knowledge in public so that others (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly okay to ask and answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site."*

Comment: For instance, there could a *real* code example that was affected by this bug. The answer would be a workaround and the explanation would contain a detailed description of the compiler bug (without any emotionally charged content, only [liquid helium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_helium)-level cold, cold facts).

Comment: Before posting, do a very deep study of self-answered questions (using 1.) the help center, 2.) lots and lots of meta question about them, and 3.) actual self-answered on Stack Overflow, both successful and failed ones). Self-answered questions are often misunderstood by uninformed users and as a result attract downvotes. Use comments to preempt them.

Comment: @PeterMortensen thank you for your encouragement. I might return in the future but right now I do not feel very motivated to contribute anymore. This is a shame because I really enjoyed it and I have provided singular answers on this site that contain hundreds of hours of work. I always enjoyed really delving into the details, which now seems to be one of the reasons my last question was closed. Had I done no research and just asked a stupid question that probably wouldn't have happened. I thought this site is about helping others. Seems like there are some more important guidelines here...

Answer (score 19):

The question is, basically, a rant that has been edited to resemble a question, but even after editing it is still a rant. Clearly you are upset that this bug still exists and that Microsoft haven't adequately addressed it.

Your post here on Meta claims that "extremely similar questions have been well-received", but the questions you link to are not similar. Looking at just your own earlier question, it asks:

> To me, many questions remain... Why does the Terminate event make a difference in this case? Is any of my code supposed to produce undefined behavior or is this actually a bug? Are there other cases where If-statements don't work the expected way? What exactly causes this bug?

Essentially your earlier question is asking "is this a bug, and if so, what exactly causes it?". That's a fine question, it is on-topic, and it is not written as a rant.

### The parts that are actually asking something

> Are there other variations of this x64 VBA-compiler bug **I am currently not aware of?**

Emphasis mine. A Stack Overflow question shouldn't say "please only tell me things I don't already know". If you already know the answer to a similar question, it's on you to distinguish your question from that similar one so that the answers will be useful to you. Further down, you did write *"For more information on what I know so far, please refer to the latter part of this post"*, but you still should rephrase the question so it's not about you or your current state of knowledge.

> How can I get it fixed?

This is asking about how to make Microsoft do something that you want them to do. At best it's a customer support question that should be targeted at Microsoft.

> Does anyone know of a way to report such bugs that will actually get them fixed?

Mostly the same problem as above, but at least part of this can be answered objectively. If what you want to know is "how can I report bugs to Microsoft?" the question should be a lot shorter; what you *really* want to know is how to make Microsoft *fix* the bugs you report, but it's totally up to Microsoft what they do in response to a bug report.

> Are there other ways in which this bug can manifest?

This is kind of open-ended. How about something like "what are the exact conditions on which this bug occurs?" or (more open-ended but still on-topic) "how can I ensure that this bug won't occur in my code?" The problem is, your earlier question, which concerns the same bug, already asked what the exact conditions are. So if you fixed your question to address all of the other issues, I don't see how it wouldn't be a duplicate of the earlier question. Any new information about the conditions on which the bug occurs ought to be written in answers to that question.

> Is there a way of filing a bug report that has been demonstrated to be effective apart from media coverage?

This is beyond a customer support question - it's a question about Microsoft's historical customer support practices. Not on-topic for Stack Overflow.

### Parts that are still a rant

There is still a lot in the question which is not asking anything, and which does not give any relevant context that might help people answer anything you did ask. I won't quote all of these parts because there is so much.

> I think it is important to raise awareness about this bug ... getting enough attention seems to be the only chance we have of getting VBA bugs fixed!

Stack Overflow questions aren't for "raising awareness" or "getting attention", they're for finding answers. Stack Overflow is not a platform for lobbying tech companies into fixing bugs in their software, nor is it a platform for organising protests against tech companies who don't fix bugs in their software.

> I have already tried submitting a "frown" through MS Office,

I can't think of any conceivable way that this helps anyone answer your question, and the screenshot of you submitting a "frown" is totally gratuitous.

> It seems I'm not the only one struggling to communicate with Microsoft
> in this regard, as there are a bunch of known bugs no one seems to
> care about: *[table of links]*

If the purpose of this table is to tell people about what you "currently know" about the bug, then just say that. It's not necessary to speculate about people "struggling to communicate" or about people "not caring about" them.

Comment: Thank you for this feedback! A lot of what you say applies to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68034271/12287457) in an identical manner. This is why I assumed it was on topic. I still struggle to see the difference but I will have to accept it.

Comment: @GWD On the face of it, that other question doesn't really seem suitable for Stack Overflow either. It has fewer problems, but it's also asking "how can I make Microsoft fix this?" which isn't on-topic. Perhaps part of the reason for its popularity is that it has an answer showing how to work around the bug, which is useful knowledge to have on Stack Overflow, despite a workaround not being what the question asks for. Moreover, if "how can I make Microsoft fix this bug" is on-topic then again I don't see how your question wouldn't still be a duplicate of this one.

Comment: even the workaround is already a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68034271/12287457). The other question is almost a duplicate of my original question, only asking a different aspect of it (which you say is off topic).

Comment: I have adjusted my question according to this feedback. Contrary to what you are writing I don't consider the screenshot of the "frown"-submit-form a rant at all. It is supposed to help people understand what I have tried. I have added a remark that sending a frown obviously includes more than clicking on the sad emoji. I now do not see any way my question is more "ranty" than the other question I linked. I think how the question is treated is doing the VBA community a big disservice. Most of the people complaining won't care about that because they are unfamiliar with VBA.

Comment: I don't know how you think *expanding* the part about you submitting a "frown" improves the question; what use is this information supposed to be to anyone answering any on-topic part of the question?

Comment: according to how to ask it is important to mention what one has tried.  Sending the frown was also mentioned in the other question I linked.

Comment: Hello @kaya3. In the post you claim: "but the questions you link to are not similar.", and then proceed to only discuss one of the questions I linked. Can you please expand on how [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68034271/12287457) is not similar?

Comment: @GWD - “What you tried” is more up the realm of a MRE not submitting a emoji to Microsoft

Comment: Hello @SecurityHound, why was it ok in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68034271/12287457) then? I have accepted the fact that many people think this is off-topic, I am just really annoyed to see a very well received question making **exactly** the same points.

Comment: @GWD posts about temporary bugs affecting millions of users tend to be far more useful, depsite possibly not following guidelines

Comment: @KevinB thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, I do not understand how the bug [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68034271/12287457) falls into a different category, it is almost identical, but is now fixed. It probably affected a similar amount of people. Not very many, but in a potentially severe manner.

Comment: it's not really worth arguing over, the votes speak for themselves. people found one useful, and not the other

Comment: @GWD - It’s not acceptable in my book. That linked question should be closed in my opinion. **I can’t properly handle the linked question because of this meta question.**

Comment: @KevinB I am aware of the votes but I have to say I'm still in disbelief because nobody is able to explain it to me. I think the difference is caused by some very very subtle nuances in the presentation and a sort of herd mentality. I am extremely disappointed at the reaction of the community. While some of the critique here was helpful, all in all, I can not understand the difference to the question I have now linked repeatedly. I will probably stop contributing to SO if such inexplicable double standards exist.

Comment: people clicked upvote, or downvote, buttons. it's not deterministic

Comment: @SecurityHound, if that is your view, that is at least consistent, I appreciate that.

Comment: @KevinB I don't care about the upvotes/downvotes, it is about the difference in moderation. Similar questions need to be moderated similarly. In fact, my question got most of the upvotes before I edited it at all.

Comment: If your question received most of its upvotes in its original form, when it was mostly a rant, that should tell you that upvotes do not always indicate that a question is suitable for Stack Overflow. For what it's worth, I will repeat my comment that I don't think the other linked question is suitable here either, and that its upvotes may be at least partly because it has a useful *answer* (which doesn't answer what is literally asked, but does answer what people might want to know if they find the question by searching).