# What to do with question where the answer are confirmed and fixed bugs?

Tags: discussion, answers, bug-reporting-process

I've seen several times comments by the author of a package that the [strange behavior addressed by the question was caused by a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47043520/changing-column-width-in-rs-kable-does-not-change-width-of-headers). The package author later fixed the bug and mentioned this in another comment.

IMO the question is solved (the correct answer: "It's a bug") and already mostly irrelevant as a new patched version was already published. But the questions still is registered as not answered. This is annoying when you are looking for unanswered questions you want to answer.

What could be done with these type of questions? To delete is maybe wrong, as some people may encounter the same problem as they still use the old (buggy) version.

My question is [similar to this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117251/what-should-be-done-with-questions-that-have-been-self-resolved-as-a-comment-ins) where the OP suggests some strategies:

- Should we vote to close?
- Should we post some sort of an answer?
- Would something like this be appropriate to flag for moderator attention, and let the moderators deal with it?
- Should we rename the question title to something standard that can be used in a search exclusion? (Maybe "SOLVED:"?)

I suggest to add to this list:

- Should we ask the package maintainer who actually solved the question, to write his/her comment as an answer (and get the reputation (s)he deserves)?
- Or are there still other strategies we should follow?

Comment: Why do you dig through old unanswered questions?  Isn't it to provide them with an answer?  You found one.

Comment: I used my favorite tags (those where I think I am most able to answer a question) and clicked at the button "unanswered". With this procedure, I try to find unanswered questions to answer them. But then it is annoying to find many questions where the answer is in the comment. --- Is there another/better procedure to find unanswered questions where one feels competent without questions already answered in the comments?

Comment: I would edit the question with a bold line at the top saying "This bug has been fixed in Library v 5.1235+". Clear, concise, unmissable for whoever has the same problem. In addition, I see no reason why OP would find this disruptive.

Comment: We definitely do _not_ add SOLVED to the title. Nor do we bother the mods with it, they already have plenty of work to do, the community can handle things like this.

Comment: If it's a bug that has been resolved, I'd post exactly this as an answer. It will get upvotes over time and maybe if the OP is still active on SO, s/he will accept your answer over the old/outdated answer.

Comment: What this really seems to be about is *"why do people not mark good answers as accepted?"* There are currently no mechanisms in place to fix this, and it's certainly unclear what mechanisms would even be possible without a thorough redefinition of what question ownership means.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There are a few things going on here.

- **[Posting an answer saying "this has been fixed in version X" or "this is a known bug" is fine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251718/how-to-deal-with-this-is-fixed-in-x-and-this-is-a-bug-answers?rq=1)**.

  You can make such an answer better by:

  - Explaining what was or is causing it
  - Providing alternative solutions
  - Mentioning and linking to: (as applicable)

    - The version in which it was fixed
    - The change log of that version
    - The bug report
- **Vote (or flag) to close (and delete) if *no* user can reproduce the issue any more**.

  If it's a service, as Tiny Giant pointed out, you may only have access to the most recent version, in which case there wouldn't be much point in keeping a question of an old version around that's no longer relevant to anyone, so such a question should be closed as unreproducible and eventually deleted. If it's anything you can download, there could theoretically still be someone out there who's still running an old version.
- [**Posting an answer summarising someone else's comment is fine**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117251/what-should-be-done-with-questions-that-have-been-self-resolved-as-a-comment-ins). You should try to provide a more complete answer, if possible, and you can also mention them in the answer and/or make it Community Wiki. You could alternatively try @-replying to them saying they should post that as an answer if you want (although you may get a reply of ["I don't want to", "You can" or "It's not really an answer"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4217/why-do-some-people-answer-in-comments)).
- **As for searching**, there's perhaps also the (still outstanding) issue of getting search to exclude [questions you've already answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163428/is-it-possible-to-exclude-questions-ive-already-answered-from-the-search-criter) (simply posting an answer may not be enough, since a question is only marked as "answered" if it has an upvoted or accepted answer) or maybe those you've already visited (since you may not want to or be able to answer any given question).
- [**DO NOT add "SOLVED" to the title**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-a-question).
- **DO NOT custom flag for moderator attention** for this reason. This is just posting answers or closing, which the community is perfectly capable of handling (in theory, anyway), so there's no need to involve mods (and a flag asking a mod to handle this will probably get declined for the same reason, since mods are more there to take care of things the community *can't* do themselves).

Comment: In the case of a service, where you only ever have access to the most recent version, such questions could just be closed as no (longer) repro and deleted.

Comment: @TinyGiant: *"Service"* is a generic term, that doesn't really mean much. In case you are referring to a web service, those *can be* versioned, and you don't always access to the latest version. There are also test setups, where outdated versions of a web service run, so your unconditional suggestion to close them questions is criminally negligent.

Comment: @IInspectable I guess I could have removed the first comma to make it clearer that I was specifically talking about services that you only ever have access to the most recent version of. I figured it was obvious that if you could access prior versions then the argument would not apply.

Comment: If you see a comment that answers the question, just repost it as an answer, with attribution. Don't worry about playing the reputation game, there are plenty of people on SO who don't care two hoots about how many brownie points they earn (they've sussed out that there's no way of spending them anyway...).