# Is "this is a known, unfixed bug" an acceptable answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

This is similar to a question [on the impossible,](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261168/3551604) but aimed at a slightly different case. When a question is butting up against a known bug in something (e.g. a library, the compiler, some analysis tool, etc), is answering with something to the effect of "this is a known issue, here's the GitHub/Bugzilla/etc tracker for it" appropriate?

Such an answer would (hopefully) have a limited shelf life, but would still be useful to the OP for the moment.

I've seen (and posted) as much as comments, but I was wondering if these sorts of statements are appropriate for answers as well.

Comment: @Nick: that exact question, not so much, but [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251718/3551604) is basically mine + more detail. I swear I searched for this first...

Comment: I fail to see how not so much: *"* ***Posting an answer saying*** "this has been fixed in version X" or ***"this is a known bug" is fine.*** *"*, but suit yourself

Comment: ... evidently I should have had stronger coffee this morning. I think I got those two posts mixed up?

Comment: /shrug, you got you answer, no harm done