# Why was this helpful and positively-scored answer about a bug deleted by a moderator?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer, moderator-intervention

I was wondering, why was this answer deleted by moderation?

[Razor code formatting issue with Visual Studio 2022](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70390496/razor-code-formatting-issue-with-visual-studio-2022/70565928#70565928)

It did help me understand the issue I was having. Though not perfect, should it have been deleted?

##### Update:

Following this discussion I edited the answer to make it more understandable and added relevant information, trying to not remove OP personal touch.

---

Picture for those who don't have the needed privileges:

[image]

Comment: What solution does it actually propose? All I see is that they have the same problem.

Comment: I thought "It's a bug" was [an acceptable answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251718/how-to-deal-with-this-is-fixed-in-x-and-this-is-a-bug-answers) @Dharman (even if the given link is not as good as the github link would've been)

Comment: @Darham: I guess the post basically says: "It's a bug in VS, here is the link to the VS issue tracker item". There's probably not more to say since it's a bug in the IDE. But it took me three times of reading to notice that it's not a "I have the same problem" post. The mentioning of the completely unrelated .NET6 upgrade also doesn't help.

Comment: @toolic, I'm sure it can, and I will do it if I find anything relevant to add, but the question is about why it was deleted.

Comment: But is it really a bug or they just think it might be a bug. If it's a bug then a solution would be to upgrade. This answer doesn't mention which version is affected or when the bug was fixed.

Comment: @Dharman it's a bug, there is probably no solution, but for it to be fixed by the vendor.

Comment: @Dharman as for your last comment, I see what you mean, so you're saying it was deleted because it was decided it does not have enough quality. FWIW the links show this has nothing to do with versions of dotnet it's bug on the IDE itself.

Comment: I wonder if "quality" actually is the issue here. My first thought was: maybe this answer has been posted to multiple questions and a mod removed the dupe answers. @Dharman can you check if that's the case?

Comment: @Tom The answer was deleted in a response to NAA flag.

Comment: @Dharman maybe the flagger mistakenly thought it were a link only answer.

Comment: @BillTürstandswithUkraine and apparently so did the person handling the flag. "Having the same problem" is definitely a combination of words to avoid at all costs, I think any interested party will have already stopped reading at that point :)

Comment: @toolic I can edit it and I did, but I can't vote for undeletion as it was made by a moderator.

Comment: @anastaciu - You can flag it though, but if the relevant information from the external link isn’t quoted and cited, then it’s not really ready to be undeleted. However, the author of the question is not using 17.4 when supposedly fixed the issue and the answer should also include the (closed) GitHub issue. In my opinion the issue is stale and unlikely to be relevant to your issue (or the authors)

Comment: I flagged the answer for review by moderators (after making some further grammatical revisions)

Comment: @TylerH I appreciate your edit, I would change the title though, in the end the discussion is really about a Visual Studio 2022 bug, I did not remove mention to .net because I didn't want to interfere further with the OPs intentions.

Comment: Here's the deal: if you can't be arsed to put more effort into your answer than "Its a bug here's a link" then it is of very little value and expected it be deleted without too much pondering by a reviewer. As soon as the "meta people" starts their "But they _try_ to answer-..." then you just need to yell "NO! Bad!" or they'll never learn. This was not a quality answer and deleting it is not a problem. Our quality bar for answers is far higher than this and we need not preserve crap for the sake of it. The purpose of SO is not to provide a library of crap and dead links, period.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Per Dharman](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426427/why-was-this-helpful-and-positively-scored-answer-about-a-bug-deleted-by-a-moder?noredirect=1#comment972397_426427), this answer was originally deleted in response to an NAA flag by a moderator.

After several revisions, it's in much better shape, and more clearly not a link-only answer or non-answer. Accordingly, a moderator has just recently undeleted it.